# Database vs Properties for User Credentials in Titanium Mobile

Tags: android, ios, passwords, titanium

I've been researching this for the last couple of days and I'm not satisfied with what I've found so far.

I'm currently writing a Titanium mobile application to be deployed on both iOS and Android simultaneously and I'm trying to decide how to best store a user's login and password for remote services on the device for the app.

I've seen arguments both for and against a SQLite database and using `Ti.App.Properties` (keychain access is not available in the current version of Titanium Mobile) but nothing comprehensive swinging me one way or the other.

Would it be best to store a user's login and password either in a SQLite database structure or a simple property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use App.Properties.  It is much easier and faster.  See http://www.titaniumdevelopment.com.au/blog/2011/10/30/app-properties-vs-sqlite-in-appcelerator-titanium-mobile/

There is also a Keychain module available at https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/787 for $5.00

Comment: I'd seen that article, very interesting read. In the absence of any other answer and the other info I've found, looks like I'll go with properties. Thanks.